# How To Pass Ajax Value to PHP Query?

Tags: ajax

So I am making a page on which there will be several portfolio items when user click on particular portfolio slider will open with images on that portfolio category.

So for that I am passing value from URL (#hash tag)

```
    <div class="portfolio1">
        <a href="#/branding">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
            <h2>Branding</h2>
                </a>
        </div>


        <div class="portfolio2">
        <a href="#/logo">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/>
            <h2>Logos</h2>
                </a>
        </div>  <div id="content2"></div>

<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'logo'
    )
 }?>
```

Now I want when user click on portfolio the a href containing category slug to be pass on WP Query  ('terms')

My Ajax Script

```
jQuery('#portfolio div a').click(function () {
var hash = window.location.hash;
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/final/ajax.php',
     data: {'hash': hash},
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#content2').html(data);
    }
});});
```

Ajax.php file

```
<?php 


$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$hash = str_replace('#', ' ', $hash);
echo $hash;?>
```

Any Help Guys.

Comment: have you even tried to look how to do ajax in wordpess :(?

Comment: well I am not good at ajax :-( that's why I was writing this work around any help?

Comment: you need to follow the documents on how to do it https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. but it is a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Create simple functions like

```
function func_for_ajax(){
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_custom_script', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    echo "simple demo ajax";
```

}

Than create your ajax pass in wordpress action threw this function name directly.

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     action: 'func_for_ajax',
     url: 'ajaxurl',
     success: function(data){
       jQuery('#content2').html(data);
     }
```

});

Comment: Your `wp_localize_script()` function call is outside the code block.

Comment: `add_action ('init','function_name');
function func_name(){
wp_localize_script( 'ajax_custom_script', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}`

Comment: You can just edit your answer. I tried to do it earlier but it wouldn't let me because it was less than 6 characters.